# $http.jsonp ERROR - MIME type ('application/json') is not executable

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp

I'm trying to call the weather api as below,

```
app.controller('getController',["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.header = "Forecast";

    var url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
    $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: url
    }).
    then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.retrieveErrorMssg = "Failed to retrieve required data. Try again.";
        });
}
```

but get the following error in console

> Refused to execute script from 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22&callback=angular.callbacks._0' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

While searching over internet, I found this is how we do when calling api from different domains. Have i missed anything in here??

Comment: What version of AngularJS?

Comment: The problem is reproduced in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/hDhH819T9T9pWvMmX6sT?p=preview)

Comment: The version is 1.5

Comment: Anyone who has any idea why it's not working??

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you get any answer?

Comment: I added this at the end of the url (callback=JSON_CALLBACK), and it worked for me

http://www.example.com/cities/2?callback=JSON_CALLBACK